# Mysterious small horizontal line below the SVG that disappear and appear

Tags: html, css, svg

I am a noob with SVG. I am trying to integrate an SVG in my layout but it is giving me a mysterious small white line below it that appears and disappears from time to time on different screen sizes can someone explain what is wrong with the SVG?
thx in advance

[Small line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyjKl.jpg)

```
<footer className={classes.Footer} id="footer">
            <img src={footerimg} alt=""/>
            <div className={classes.Content}>
            </div>
</footer>

// my css 
.Footer {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border: 2px solid red;
flex-flow: column;
}

 .Footer img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

 .Content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e58f8;
  height: 500px;
}
```

the main SVG file is

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" width="2003" height="226.55" style="">
    <rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#5e58f8;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>svgFooter2</title>
    <g class="currentLayer" style="">
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M0,226.55000001192093 S215.26,-91.44999998807907 695.74,26.07000001192093 C1405,199.55000001192093 2003,8.550000011920929 2003,8.550000011920929 V226.55000001192093 z" id="svg_1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It would be nice if people can share why this horizontal line would appear. What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Removing the border of img tag will help you for that**

```css
.Footer {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border: 2px solid red;
flex-flow: column;
}

 .Footer img {
   display: block;
   border:none;
    width: 100%;
}

 .Content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5e58f8;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<footer className=Footer id="footer">
            <img src=err.png alt="wrong"/>
            <div className=Content>
            </div>
</footer>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" width="2003" height="226.55" style="">
    <rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#5e58f8;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>svgFooter2</title>
    <g class="currentLayer" style="">
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M0,226.55000001192093 S215.26,-91.44999998807907 695.74,26.07000001192093 C1405,199.55000001192093 2003,8.550000011920929 2003,8.550000011920929 V226.55000001192093 z" id="svg_1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I thought about it, and also tried it but still not resolving the problem. the line is not appearing permanently but in some screen sizes yes and other screen sizes not at all

Comment: Same happens to me... I made a custom section border with svg but a thin line (1px maybe) appears between my svg and the element supossed to be bordered

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I hope this solution can help anyone still struggling with this.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70689442/14519770).

chrwahl's answer gives 4 solutions. I applied the 3rd one to your example and the line went away. All it does is add a transform attribute to the path which translates the svg 1 pixel on the y-axis. You can control how far up or down you need it with that attribute.

```css
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex-flow: column;
  }

  .Footer img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .Content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5e58f8;
    height: 500px;
  }
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" width="2003" height="226.55" style="">
    <rect id="backgroundrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#5e58f8;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>svgFooter2</title>
    <g class="currentLayer" style="">
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        
        <!-- Note the transform   -->
        <path 
        transform="translate(0 1)" 
        class="cls-1" 
        d="M0,226.55000001192093 S215.26,-91.44999998807907 695.74,26.07000001192093 C1405,199.55000001192093 2003,8.550000011920929 2003,8.550000011920929 V226.55000001192093 z" id="svg_1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
  <div class="Content">

  </div>
</footer>
```

---

However, you said it disappears on different screen sizes. [SmilyLily's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70696191/14519770) fixed that issue for me. Its basically adding a negative margin to the svg which hides the clipping. My line appeared on the bottom of my svg. When I added a bottom margin, the line went away even when resizing the page. Your CSS rule may look different, but as long as it's applied to the SVG, the clipping will go away.

```
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -5px;  /* Adding this line fixed it */
}
```